# Windows manager doesn't switch to previous app

Tags: 23.10

Can't express it more specific, but the problem is that: when I start my laptop (Ubuntu 23.10), open some apps (VSCode, DocumentViewer, Mozila and so on) my default way to switch between apps opened is 'super'+ 'tab' to switch to previously opened app and 'super' + '~' to change to another tab of current app. But after some time or some action (I have not found the trigger so far) Ubuntu stops changing tabs by those commands and always stay at current app (it's also possible to choose an app manually by arrows). I'm a CS student, my routine is using 3 displays so always have 3 apps opened and switch between them often, so it's almost crucial functionality for me. Any advice how to fix it or maybe what process to restart to make it works again (but without closing apps because I spend several minutes to open all of them again)?

P.S. Sorry for my poor English...